# How can I use ellipsis in a link that have :after pseudo element

Tags: css

I've a link as shown in image bellow

[image]

What I want is to do, is apply

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

so in this case the word "Page" will be replaced by ellipsis, but still having the arrow, which is an :after element of the link.

Link code is this:

```
.next-lesson:after{
background: url("img/icons.png") no-repeat -9px -91px;
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
content: "";
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What's your current code for styling the `a` and its `:after`?

Comment: I created a fiddle. I can reproduce his issue and are unable to fix it (so far): http://jsfiddle.net/DNhsE/

Comment: I've updated the question with link css.

Comment: What about `.next-lesson`?

Comment: `.next-lesson`don't have any attribute by now, but the link is wrapped by a parent div, with fixed size, it's a span3 as I'm using bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your last comment you can do the following:

Declare `position:relative` on the link's parent div and `position:absolute` on the link's pseudo-element to make it independent from the `a` and its declared `overflow:hidden`. Adjust the position accordingly and everything should be fine.

Comment: That seems to work! Now I just need to tweak it a bit. Thank you!